# How I create another index using the elastic search?

Tags: c#, asp.net, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-5

I am new to Elasticsearch and NEST etc. using c#. So, far I have learned and managed to write a code to create an index but the problem is how do I create a second table (type). If I create it the same way then it only creates one table and not the second one.

Code:

```
    public static void CreateIndex()
    {
        ConnectionSettings settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
        settings.DefaultIndex("store");
        ElasticClient client = new ElasticClient(settings);
        client.Indices.Delete(Indices.Index("store"));
        var indexSettings = client.Indices.Exists("store");
        if (!indexSettings.Exists)
        {
            var response = client.Indices.Create(Indices.Index("store"));
        }

    }

    public static void CreateSeed()
    {
        int seedValue = 1;
        int limitValue = 20000;

        IList<stores> List = new List<stores>();

        ConnectionSettings settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
        settings.DefaultIndex("store");
        ElasticClient esClient = new ElasticClient(settings);
       
            var item = new store() { ID = seedValue, Title = "item" + seedValue.ToString(), IsPublished = true };
            var response = esClient.IndexAsync(item, idx => idx.Index("store"));
           
        

    }
    /// <summary>  
    ///   
    /// </summary>  
    public static void CreateMappings()
    {
        ConnectionSettings settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
        settings.DefaultIndex("store");
        ElasticClient esClient = new ElasticClient(settings);
        esClient.Map<stores>(m =>
        {
            var putMappingDescriptor = m.Index(Indices.Index("store")).AutoMap();
            return putMappingDescriptor;
        });
    }
```

This create a store index and can be retrieved. However, if I create another table of different name e.g. itemsstore the same way, the older one doesn't exist anywhere.

Why? How do I create a new second table?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the example given, it looks like this will

1. delete `"store"` index
2. check if the `"store"` index exists (it won't as it was just deleted)
3. create a `"store"` index
4. set the default index to use as the `"store"` index (which will be created on indexing the first document, if it doesn't exist)
5. index `store` types into a `"store"` index
6. create a mapping for the `"store"` index

In summary, the example looks like it only interacts with a `"store"` index.

A simple example to create two indices is

```cs
var client = new ElasticClient();
var createIndexResponse = await client.Indices.CreateAsync("store");

if (!createIndexResponse.IsValid)
{
    // take some action e.g. logging, exception, etc.
    // To keep the example simple, just throw an exception
    throw new Exception(createIndexResponse.DebugInformation);
}

createIndexResponse = await client.Indices.CreateAsync("itemsstore");

if (!createIndexResponse.IsValid)
{
    throw new Exception(createIndexResponse.DebugInformation);
}
```

The [walkthrough on building a Nuget search web application may be useful](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net-example). The different branches have walkthroughs for different version of the client. For example, the [7.x branch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net-example/tree/7.x) is for NEST 7.x, with [7.x-codecomplete](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net-example/tree/7.x-codecomplete) showing the completed example. It'll demonstrate a number of Elasticsearch and search related concepts.

Comment: i will try this one and let you know, Russ. Thanks man.